# Перестал работать HDD, в новом ноутбуке

Tags: windows, hdd, железо

Ноут просто завис, выключили зажатием кнопки питания

Стоит win10 лицензионная

Биос HDD не видит, Ubuntu (live cd) видит, но не монтирует

Вывод `dmesg | grep ata1`

`ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
ata1: device not ready (errno=-16)
ata1: reset failed, giving up
ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
ata1: device not ready (errno=-16)
ata1: reset failed, giving up
ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
ata1: device not ready (errno=-16)
ata1: reset failed, giving up
ata1: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
ata1: device not ready (errno=-16)
ata1: reset failed, giving up`

Comment: `mhdd`, `victoria`?

Comment: в `mhdd` есть три порта, на каждый `Drive is not ready`

Comment: А контроллер винта в `ide mode`?

Comment: Раз новый то чините/меняйте по гарантии

Comment: Ноут не lenovo часом?

Comment: Виктор, да lenovo